# Confused with meaning of reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, wav, reinterpret-cast, riff

Clarification is needed with `reinterpret_cast`.

I am building `.wav` file where various data is inputted as 2 or 4 bytes in hexadecimal bits (if I am correct).

Then, I came across a simple function like this:

```
void writeToFile(std::ofstream &file, int value, int size)
{
    file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), size);
}
```

As far as I understand what `reinterpret_cast` does is that it changes the data type in the address a pointer points to!

For example:

```
int* intPtr{ new int{7} };
char* charPtr{ reinterpret_cast<char*>(intPtr) };
```

So here we got a new pointer that is supposed to point to `char` value instead of original `int`.

If so, then I don't understand validity of the above function `void writeToFile(std::ofstream &file,  int value, int size)`, because if I follow my logic, then in this function an int `value` can't be written to `file` as the pointer  supposedly points to `char` value, not `int`!

P.S. Even if a file is opened in `std::ios::binary` mode, how does it exactly work? How do bits of `int` become bits of `char`?

Comment: Unrelated nitpick: A bit is always binary, never hexadecimal.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` doesn't change data. It only changes how the compiler interprets the data. The same data causes different behavior depending on the interpretation, e.g. because of function overloading. `std::cout` can print the same data as `97` or `a` depending on the data type. Both values have the same bit pattern on many systems.

Comment: Remember `char` acts as byte in C++. So what is happening is the bytes of the machine representation of the integer value are written out. I'm guessing the argument `size` is `sizeof(int)` or equivalent. It looks like somewhere there's an assumption that the byte ordering on your hardware platform is applicable to the .wav file.

Comment: Perhaps OP does not know that _all types_ in memory or files are "a collection of bytes", and it is up a program to decide whether any collection of bytes should be treated as an `int` or any other type.

Comment: [Dupe1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242711/reinterpret-casted-value-varies-by-compiler), [Dupe2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39854610/casting-int-pointer-to-char-pointer), [Dupe3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471703/why-cant-we-static-cast-a-char-pointer-to-an-int-pointer) and [Dupe4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564574/testing-for-endianness-why-does-the-following-code-work).